# Is this a valid and correct skeleton class/struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been watching [Alexander Stepanov](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIHAEYyoTUc) programming C++ with components and he, as usual, has some strong opinions. I did like one of his assertions that we use regular, semi-regular and fully ordered types. So I decided to pull together a skeleton class (pair in this case) and wonder if there are any valid reasons for using this skeleton or something different. I realise there is no silver bullet and am not looking for one, but I am interested in the basics being programmatically consistent and correct. Alex seemed to loosely suggest that such a start position would be valid.

I hope this is a valid question, I think some of the areas of concern are:

- Is it valid to refer to class as regular/semiregular/fullyordered?
  (It's hard to find examples.)
- Are there strong reasons for non-member `friend`/non-`friend` member functions? (I'm thinking here of the [Dr.
  Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) showing non-member (non-`friend`) functions improving encapsulation.)
- Should `friend` requirements define member/non member functions?
- Is it a good rule that each of these groups are implemented fully if at least one member of that group is? I.e. `==` must also be implemented with `!=` etc. Sort of as an extension to the big 4 or 5 or 6 construction or regular methods :-)

**This is C++11 that MSVC 2012 can handle. Clang, gcc etc. can improve this loads, but for now I am using MSVC 2012 as the baseline. `friend` is not required in these functions. I have included it to try and cover a normal "template" (if I create a template/snippet) for use where there are private data members. My intent is *not* to use this as a snippet, though.**

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct MyClass {     
    T first;
    U second;

    // semiregular

    MyClass(const MyClass& other)
        : first(other.first),
          second(other.second)
    {}

    MyClass(MyClass&& other)
        : first(std::move(other.first)),
          second(std::move(other.second))
    {}

    MyClass()
        : first(),
          second()
    {}

    ~MyClass()
    {}

    MyClass& operator=(MyClass other) {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    // regular
    friend
    bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
        return std::tie(lhs.first, lhs.second)
                   == std::tie(rhs.first, rhs.second);
    }

    friend
    bool operator!=(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
        return !operator==(lhs, rhs);
    }

    // fully ordered
    friend
    bool operator<(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
        return std::tie(lhs.first, lhs.second)
                   < std::tie(rhs.first, rhs.second);
    }

    friend
    bool operator>(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
        return operator<(rhs, lhs);
    }

    friend
    bool operator<=(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
        return !operator>(lhs, rhs);
    }

    friend
    bool operator>=(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
        return !operator<(lhs, rhs);
    } 
};

// swap
void swap(MyClass& lhs, MyClass& rhs) /* noexcept */ {
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.first, rhs.first);
    swap(lhs.second, rhs.second);
}


#endif // MY_CLASS_H
```

Comment: Can you provide a definition of *regular*, *semi-regular* and *fully ordered* types? As it stands now, it's a bit hard to understand your question fully without watching the hour long video.

Comment: @Lstor yes as far as I can tell from Alex. it is semi-regular is construction move and assignment (I added move), regular is equality comparable and fully ordered is < and all associated members to allow stable sort.

Comment: I'm not sure of `std::swap(a, a)` is guaranteed to be safe or not. If not, you should check for self-assignment in `op=()`.

Comment: @Lstor: Although I've never seen `std::swap()` used in `operator=` before, it got me thinking about private data members.  When you modify their declarations, don't you also update `operator=` accordingly?  That seems to reduce maintainability, at least the way I'm thinking about it.

Comment: His `op=()` takes `rhs` by value. It's normal to take it by `const&`. I'm not even completely sure taking by value is valid, but I presume it is. When taking by value, the swapped object is just a temporary, so destructively changing the values is not harmful.

Comment: @Jamal See [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9728/c-code-reviews) regarding maintainability.

Comment: @Lstor That's where a move aware swap works well, it can make use of rvalue's saving an extra temporary and if defined correctly should be `noexcept` (again msvc 2012 stops us using this important feature)

Comment: @Lstor It’s valid and recommended. OP’s implementation is idiomatic for `operator=` nowadays.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the insight. I guess I should revisit the basics to see what's changed and what I need to unlearn.

Comment: @Lstor, the operator= by-value implementation is called the ["copy&swap idiom"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of hard to tell what you're really asking. Without knowing what you're asking, it's hard to provide a helpful and meaningful answer. I will try regardless. Feel free to point me in the right direction if I'm missing the point.

---

> *Is it valid to refer to class as regular/semiregular/fully ordered?*

While I'm not familiar with the terminology, the distinctions are useful. These classifications let you reason about a class. For example, `std::list<T>::sort()` requires that `operator<` is defined for `T`. This is part of what Java and C# interfaces and the suggested C++ *concepts* feature is about. Note that they aren't necessarily accumulative: A type can be "fully ordered" without being "semi-regular".

However, I can't see a good reason for sorting types into *only* these categories. Stepanov may have some deeper insight here.

---

> *Are there strong reasons for non-member* `friend`*/non-*`friend` *member functions?*

Like Scott Meyers points out in the article you link to, non-member non-`friend`functions improve encapsulation, which leads to looser coupling. (Looser coupling in turn leads to better complexity handling, replaceable components, more testable interfaces and so on. These are *good things*.)

Regarding non-member `friend` functions, I personally consider them a code smell. It doesn't *necessarily* mean that the code is dirty, but in most cases you don't want `friend`s. (*Even without* `friend`*s, you can still* `throw party;`*!*) Declaring a `friend` breaks encapsulation and leads to tighter coupling, which is the opposite of what we want.

(If you do have `friend`s, make sure they interact with an interface (i.e. member function) and not directly with private variables/implementation details.)

---

> *Should* `friend` *requirements define member/non-member functions?*

I am reading the question as: *"Should functions that need to be declared `friend` be member functions instead?"*

For functions that are *not* part of the class' public interface, the answer is **yes, definitely**. They should be `private` member functions.

For functions that *are* part of the public interface: Unless you have a specific reason to make that function non-member, **it should be a member function**. The point Scott Meyers is making, however, is this: If the function can use the class' public interface instead of being non-member `friend` or a member function, it should do so: It should be a non-member, non-`friend` function that interacts with the type through the type's public interface.

My basic guideline is this: **Can the function make use of only the public interface? Then make it non-member, non-`friend`. If not, make it a member function.** However, **don't** extend the public interface *more than otherwise necessary* just to allow a function to be non-member, non-`friend`. If you have to extend the public interface for just a single function, then that function should probably be a member function instead.

---

> Is it a good rule that each of these groups are implemented fully if at least one member of that group is?

When defining one of assignment operator, destructor or copy constructor, [the Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) comes into play and you should probably define the others.

For the categories Stepanov talks about: **Yes, if you implement one part of the groups of operators, you should probably implement the others.** This is because you should follow [the Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Users of a type expect that if you can say `a == b`, then you should be able to say `a != b` as well.

The exception is what he refers to as *regular*: A type that is constructable may not need to be copyable or movable.

Comment: Thanks for that, a great response to a wide question really. I have a couple of suggestions. I don't think Stepanov suggests only these types but for generic programming like he does it he makes great use of associativity and commutativity and these groups perhaps make sense there. I agree with the friend issues with one query, if a function can only be useful for a public interface then why not include it in the object (if it can never be useful outside it for other objects). I know Stepanov has many issues with some of Scott Meyers views, not sure about this one. cont.

Comment: I am also not sure these groups are not accumulative or the regular types are different (group of three/4/5 etc.) it seems to me these should all be declared, even if declared private (or better =delete or default or defined later hand crafted). I think this also satisfies the rule of no astonishment (an object assigned that was never meant to etc.). It also makes programer intent clear and not rely on what a compiler default creates or not (msvc has some weird broken rules here with move for instance).

Comment: If I understand you correctly: If a function can only ever be useful for the class itself, it should probably not even be part of the class' public interface. And, like you say, if a type is not meant to be assignable, then you would have to hide (or `= delete`) its assignment operator and so on.

Comment: Yes, kinda :-) I mean if a method is public, but only applicable to the object itself i.e. if we had a prime object that is only prime numbers (so ++p would go to next prime etc.) and we had a member PrimePosition() that returned the position of the current prime or perhaps just to make it more clear a method PrimePosition(Prime p); that returned the position of the prime, then even as a non member non friend this would be floating around the code somewhere outside the object and of no use to any other object. In this case is there a good reason not to have it as a member ?

Comment: I think in that case it should be a `private` member function.

Comment: Even though it would be useful for clients to call it ?

Comment: If it's useful for clients to call it, then it should be part of the public interface, which means that it should be a non-member, non-`friend` unless it needs special access. It wouldn't be "floating around" -- normally it would be kept in the same namespace and translation unit as the class it belongs to.

Comment: I am assuming in this case this Prime method could iterate through primes it calculates internally, so not possible, it's only an example. Somebody may say I want to know which position 17 is in the list of primes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9733/discussion-between-lstor-and-dirvine)

Comment: this is exactly the point, I cannot see how having it external to the class would buy anything as it should be part of the object and logically would be in both cases, but external seems dijointed. I am pretty sure I can put this down to a style preference perhaps, so I won't pursue it :-) Your opinion seems to be held by the majority and more likely valid.